# How to crop user pfp and make it so that the cropped areas are transparent?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

````
    ```import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from io import BytesIO
    @bot.command()
        async def wanted(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
            if user == None:
                user = ctx.author
        
            wanted = Image.open("wanted.jpg")
        
            asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
            data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
            pfp = Image.open(data)
        
            bigsize = (pfp.size[0] * 3, pfp.size[1] * 3)
            mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
            draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
            mask = mask.resize(pfp.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            pfp.putalpha(mask)
        
            pfp = pfp.resize((382,298))
            output = ImageOps.fit(pfp, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
        
            output.putalpha(mask)
        
            wanted.paste(pfp, (40,221))
            wanted.save("profile.png")
        
        
            await ctx.reply(file = discord.File("profile.png"))

bot.run("Token")
````

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/972770801671626802/989414751127891998/unknown.png

this is the code im using and this is the result. I want the edges of the pfp to be transparent

I'm trying to crop out the black areas as transparent and leave the image in a circular shape

Comment: Your question is not **minimal** - do I need to get involved with `async` to answer, or know what `bot` is?, nor is it **complete** - you have unhelpfully removed the `import` statements, nor is it **runnable**. Please click [edit] and update it. Please also try to show what result you are hoping for, even if only mocked up. Thank you.

Comment: If you're RGBA then you could use the alpha channel to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-background-image-transparent-using-python/

```py
import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from io import BytesIO
    @bot.command()
        async def wanted(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
            if user == None:
                user = ctx.author
        
            wanted = Image.open("wanted.jpg")
        
            asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
            data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
            pfp = Image.open(data)
        
            bigsize = (pfp.size[0] * 3, pfp.size[1] * 3)
            mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
            draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
            mask = mask.resize(pfp.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            pfp.putalpha(mask)
        
            pfp = pfp.resize((382,298))
            output = ImageOps.fit(pfp, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
        
            output.putalpha(mask)
            img = pfp.convert("RGBA")
            datas = img.getdata()
            newData = []
            for items in datas:
              if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
                   newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
              else:
                   newData.append(item)
  
            img.putdata(newData)
            img.save("pfp.png", "PNG")
            img2=Image.open("pfp.png")
            wanted.paste(img2, (40,221))
            wanted.save("profile.png")
        
        
            await ctx.reply(file = discord.File("profile.png"))

bot.run("Token")
```